# Launching iTunes Store within App with Search

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes, storekit

I'm creating an iOS radio station app, and I can't find a solution to what I thought was a simple problem. If my radio station plays an song/album people want to buy, **how can I just launch the iTunes Store and have it open with a search results for that track or album?**

I know I can use the Apple Search API to get a json of the search results and parse that for the best search results, and I know I can open the iTunes store with https://itunes.apple.com/ (if I try to append a search string to this, I get the metadata back) or with SKStoreProductViewController if I know the product ID.

**But is there a way to simply open the iTunes Store to open with search results for a song or album (or both) without having to evaluate the search metadata and send them to one (perhaps wrong) product?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using URL Scheme's and a tool called iTunes Link Maker. Documentation can be found for iTunes on Apple's website [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iTunesLinks/iTunesLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH3-SW1)

> The iTunes URL scheme is used to link to content on the iTunes Music
>   Store. The iTunes URL format is complicated to construct, so you
>   create it using an online tool called iTunes Link Maker. The tool
>   allows you to select a country destination and media type, and then
>   search by song, album, or artist. After you select the item you want
>   to link to, it generates the corresponding URL.

http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/

Comment: Maybe it's so obvious I'm not seeing it, but I've looked through this previously, and it seems like the link maker is for finding the reference for one object, not invoking a search. What am I missing here?  "The tool allows you to select a country destination and media type, and then search by song, album, or artist. After you select the item you want to link to, it generates the corresponding URL"

Comment: A good suggestion, but not really. After testing this out a bit, if there's a one word (e.g. "U2") band or album name that seemingly corresponds to an artist or collections page, it will take you to search results for that in iTunes. However, if you use another term that includes an album and/or track name, it doesn't work.

Comment: @yodel is it possible that it is how you are formatting the spaces in the url? For example itunes.com/u2+somealbum

Comment: @yodel hmm, im not sure then. Ill let you know if I think of something.